# How to replace element in array of models using optimized approach?

Tags: arrays, swift

If there is an `Array` as below containing `User` instances.

```
class User {
     var id: String
     var name: String

    init(id: String, name: String) {
     self.id = id
     self.name = name
    }
}
```

Now if there are 5 user models having ids from 1 to 5 and are stored in the array as below (no matter what the name is)

```
var userModels = [user1,user2,user3,user4,user5]
```

Now suppose there is an instance I am creating manually with id `1`

```
let latestUser = User(id: "1", name: "Updated Name") //id 1 is already there but this is the updated model
```

is there any way to find the index of the user model whose index is 1 without `filter` so that I can replace the instance like this

Using Array extension or anything.Can we have the constraint for `index(of: )` for property id ???

```
let indexOfUser1 = userModels.index(of: latestUser) // It should return 1.
userModels[indexOfUser1] = latestUser //Replacing the user with id 1 with the latest one
```

Like this (as we do the `subscript`)

```
extension Array where Element: User { 
   //TODO: indexOf constraint for specific property

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*find the index of the user model whose index is 1*"? Did you mean "find the index of the user model whose `id` is 1"?

Comment: I want to replace user1 with latestUser with optimized approach.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `Equatable`:

```
class User: Equatable {
    var id: String
    var name: String

    init(id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    static func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
array.index(of: someUser)
```